# Login Authentication In IBM Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I am using Jquery Mobile to start with IBM worklight project. I have created a Login Page. Whenever user click on the submit button I need the function too run to check for the username and password in the Database.

Database -> I am using MY SQl database. Using the command client I have added the tables, username Password and values. I need to check this table whenever user clicks on the submit button. IBM worklight tutorial says I need to add the JDBC jar file to server/lib. I have copy pasted the downloaded file on the same folder.

I don`t know whether I need to make my own Custom login Module or default thing is available.

There Isn`t a clear examples available in the IBM website for the Authentication. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest reading the following:

- Authentication concepts
- Adapter-based authentication + Exercise and code sample
- Adapter framework overview
- SQL adapter – Communicating with SQL database + Exercise and code sample

from the [Getting Started](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) page. Also take a look at [InfoCenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.doc%2Fwl_home.html) if you need more documentation.

From the adapter-based auth code sample, you can start by replacing:

`if(username == "worklight" && password == "worklight")` with a call to your backend (see sql adapter code sample) that checks if the username and password are valid.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! I`m reading all these pdfs now.